# How to place two images side by side with text above in HTML

Tags: css, html

I am trying to place two images in html (with css) side by side with a small padding to get a space between the two, with some text above the two. This would be inside the "section div" I managed to get them side by side but all the work got lost and i did not manage to place the text above the images. 
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```css
#header {
  background-color:#ff6600;
  color:white;
  text-align:left;
  padding:2px;
}
#nav {
  line-height:30px;
  background-color:#fff000;
  height:350px;
  width:189px;
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
}
#section {
  width:350px;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
}
#footer {
  background-color:#737373;
  color:white;
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
}
#container {
  margin:auto;
  width:900px;
  text-align:left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!---container--->
  <div id="header">
    <h1>JORDAS</h1>

  </div>
  <!--header-->

  <div id="nav">
    <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a>
    <br>
    <a href="page1.html">Teltat</a>
    <br>
    <a href="page2.html">Palvelut</a>
    <br>
    <a href="page3.html">Yhteistiedot</a>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="section">
    <a href="page2.html"><h1>Pro</h1></a>
    <div class="main_block">

      <div class="inner_block">
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png>
      </div>

      <div class="inner_block">
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--mainblock-->
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <h3>POP-UP TELTTOJEN YKKÖNEN </h3>
  </div>
  <!--footer-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcuyg17r/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More simple solution, to use `inline-block` property for images wrapers and similar `width` for images and wrapers:

```
.inner_block {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/wcuyg17r/4/)

Comment: Hello, Igor! This was a simple solution to my problem! Do I  make a div with padding for a second link above the following(2) picture? Thanks!

Comment: @H.Julius, sorry, what do you need? did you mean, if will be used bigger text above image? or your question was about paddings between divs?)

Comment: @H.Julius, and what solution do you have now?

Comment: I went with your solution! I tried to ask that how do i Get this "basic" Link over the second image :)   https://jsfiddle.net/wcuyg17r/5/

Comment: @H.Julius, if I clearly understood, here what you looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/wcuyg17r/6/

Answer (score 1):

Your images are inside divs which are block level by default. Set them to either `inline` or `inline-block` to get the images to sit next to each other:

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #header {
   background-color: #ff6600;
   color: white;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 2px;
 }
 #nav {
   line-height: 30px;
   background-color: #fff000;
   height: 350px;
   width: 189px;
   float: left;
   padding: 5px;
 }
 #section {
   width: 350px;
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 #footer {
   background-color: #737373;
   color: white;
   clear: both;
   text-align: center;
 }
 #container {
   margin: auto;
   width: 900px;
   text-align: left;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .inner_block {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!---container--->
  <div id="header">
    <h1>JORDAS</h1>

  </div>
  <!--header-->

  <div id="nav">
    <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a>
    <br>
    <a href="page1.html">Teltat</a>
    <br>
    <a href="page2.html">Palvelut</a>
    <br>
    <a href="page3.html">Yhteistiedot</a>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="section">
    <a href="page2.html"><h1>Pro</h1></a>
    <div class="main_block">

      <div class="inner_block">
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png>
      </div>

      <div class="inner_block">
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--mainblock-->
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <h3>POP-UP TELTTOJEN YKKÖNEN </h3>
  </div>
  <!--footer-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if that jsfiddle fits your expectations. If not explain your issue.

```css
 <style>

body{margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
 #header {
    background-color:#ff6600;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    padding:2px;
 }

#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#fff000;
    height:350px;
    width:189px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;

}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
#footer {
    background-color:#737373;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    
 
}
#container {
 margin:auto;
 width:900px;
 text-align:left;
 overflow: hidden;

}

.inner_block{
  width:45%;
  display:inline-block;
}

#section{
  text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

```html
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
 <body>
 <div id="container"><!---container--->
<div id="header">
<h1>JORDAS</h1>

</div><!--header-->

<div id="nav">
<a href="index.html">Etusivu</a> <br>
<a href="page1.html">Teltat</a><br>
<a href="page2.html">Palvelut</a><br>
<a href="page3.html">Yhteistiedot</a><br>
</div>

<div id="section">
<a href="page2.html"><h1>Pro</h1></a>
<div class="main_block">

    <div class="inner_block">
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png>
    </div>

    <div class="inner_block">
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png >
    </div>    

</div><!--mainblock-->
</div>

<div id="footer">
<h3>POP-UP TELTTOJEN YKKÖNEN </h3>
 </div><!--footer-->
</div> <!--container-->
</body>
```

Comment: Hello! I just copy-pasted your code into notepad++, but without results. The images i am using are h:45px and w:45px. it works just like i want it to work in jsfiddle thou. I tested it in both firefox and chrome, and pasted from notepad++ to jsfiddle to check for errors  but it worked perfectly. This is the right solution but how comes it only works in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem.

```
.inner_block{
   float: left;
 }
```